# Tool recommendation for generating a SOAP web service in Java

Tags: java, soap

I'm now learning JavaEE, and I'd like to know which cool tools are out there for generating a SOAP Web Service (from classes or from WSDLs).

I value simplicity above everything else. If possible, something integrable into Eclipse IDE.

By the way, I have made a HelloWorld WS using eclipse's WTP, but I don't know if this is the way it is done in real world practice.

Thanks, and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Apache CXF** - http://cxf.apache.org,

If you're using spring, **Spring Web Services** - http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/

Comment: Also there is soapui for testing soap web services

Answer (score 0):

[SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/) is a very useful tool for Testing Web Services. It also has Plugin for Eclipse, Netbeans

Comment: Yes, I've used it, but it's only for testing, isn't it?

Comment: @Mister Smith : yes, its for testing. Glad to know that you have already used it. Apache CXF (as mentioned by Dzhu) is also a good one. Used it to generate Java Client Code directly from WSDL.